# I cannot get code to separate and compare array data correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

I've got an fstream input file that has [N] lines or items. I've written code to decide which items are triangles and which are rectangles and which are circles. I've got to isolate just the triangle items and then compare them to see if they are equal to +/- 0.1 the area of all the other triangle items. Then I have to cout the equal pairs of items as uppercase char letters.

Here's my code so far but it's not working correctly. It's outputting L&L, which is incorrect. It should say E&L because the two identical triangles in my array are on lines 5&12, Not 12&12. How do I fix this?

```
   int ItmM = 0;
   ItmN = 0;
   int j = 0;

   for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
   {
     if (btype[i] == Triangles)
     {
       TA[i] = (0.5 * (D[i] * E[i]));

       for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
       {
         if (TA[i] - 0.1 < TA[j] && TA[j] < TA[i] + 0.1)
         {
           TA[j] = TA[i];
           ItmM = i;
           ItmN = j;

   cout << "4. Triangular blocks that are the same size = "
        << (char)('A' + ItmM) << "&" << (char)('A' + ItmM)
        << endl;

         }
       }
     }
   }
```

I've edited the above code twice. It's still outputting L&L. Should be E&L, (5&12)

Comment: Is `j` always supposed to be `0`? I don't see you changing its value anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `TriangleAreaE = TrangleArea[j]`, and as `j` is always`0`, you are comparing every triangle with the first one. The 5th and 12th never get compared.

You should use a nested loop to compare every pair of triangles:

```
for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
  if ( /*...*/ )
  {
    /*...*/
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
       // compare TriangleArea[i] with TriangleArea[j], if j is a triangle
    }
  }
}
```

You can fill in the detail, as this seems to be a homework problem.

And you should edit your existing posts instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry, will do. Very new to the website and to C++. My professor is very intelligent but he teaches us by showing overhead projections so I've learned everything I know about c++ from bucky's tutorials on thenewboston.

Answer (score 0):

The value of j never changes in the code you posted. You just compare the area of each triangle with the first one in the list. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should be able to make it work with a nested for loop:

```
TriangleArea[0]= whatever

for(j=0; j<M; j++)
{
    for(i=j+1;i<m;i++)
    {
         // rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never modify j, so you are always comparing with the first triangle (triangle A), so it's not really a suprise that it is equal to itself. What you need to do is loop over all already processed triangles and compare, so basically

```
for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
   if (btype[i] == Triangles)  //btype[i] declared earlier in larger code
   {
     TriangleArea[i] = (0.5 * (D[i] * E[i]));

     for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
     { 
       //Insert the comparison here
     }
   }
}
```

Of course your positioning of the `cout` will only print the last pair of equal sized pair, so judging from the text in your question, you might want to put the `cout` inside your loops.

Comment: I tried putting the cout inside the loop. I'm not sure if I put it in the right place though. I edited the above code to show my up to date changes. It's still outputting L&L, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
(char)('A' + ItemNumberM) << "&" << (char)('A' + ItemNumberM)
```

This line prints the same item number twice.  Is one of those supposed to be `ItemNumberN`?

Comment: Yes, one is supposed to be ItmN

Comment: @lprater1: You edited your code with shorter names, but the problem's still there.  You're printing `ItmM` (which is `L` twice), that's why you see `L & L`.